# history.push is not redirecting to specific page with ReactJs

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a ReactJS app where I have a login screen and when I login successfully, I want to redirect it to my main page but for some reason, I can't get this to work.

I'm using the `react-router-dom` library.

I'm initializing my app in the index.html using the following:

```
ReactDOM.render(
  <BrowserRouter>
    <App />
  </BrowserRouter>,
  document.getElementById("root")
);
```

and in my app.jsx, my render function uses the following code:

```
class App extends Component {
  state = {};
  render() {
    const isAuthenticated = IsAuthenticated();
    return (
      <AuthContext.Provider value={isAuthenticated}>
        <main className="container">
          {isAuthenticated ? <NavBar /> : null}
          <Switch>
            <PrivateRoute path="/home" component={Home} />
            {isAuthenticated ? (
              <Redirect to="/members" />
            ) : (
              <Route path="/login" component={LoginForm} />
            )}
            <PrivateRoute path="/" exact component={Home} />
          </Switch>
        </main>
      </AuthContext.Provider>
    );
  }
}
```

Note that I've simplified the above code as I have many other pages defined in there but this is the core of it anyway.

I've based my code on an article that I found:

[Building Basic React Authentication](https://medium.com/better-programming/building-basic-react-authentication-e20a574d5e71)

Note that I haven't followed all the steps in this article as I've adjusted based on my requirements.

This is the code I'm using when click my login button and I successfully login:

```
  var result = await httpService.post(loginEndPoint, loginCredentials);
  const user = result.data;
  localStorage.setItem("user", JSON.stringify(user));
  this.props.history.replace("/home");
  this.props.history.push("/home");
```

I've left both the `history.replace` as I wanted to remove my "login" page once I successfully logged in and wanted to make sure I would not be able to come back to the login page until my token expired.

Then I try to use the `history.push` to go from my login page to my home page but it is somehow remaining on my login page but once I refresh the app in the browser via F5, it does redirect to the home page as my token is valid.

Any ideas why the this.props.history.push is not "redirecting" to my home page?

Let me know if I need to provide any additional code or information.

Thanks.

**Update-1:**

I don't think the problem is with .push or redirect as I accidently used a page that did not exists in my route after logging in and it redirected to the NotFound route which means routing to another page is working.

This is my full route definition:

```
  <AuthContext.Provider value={isAuthenticated}>
    <main className="container">
      <ToastContainer />
      {isAuthenticated ? <NavBar /> : null}
      <Switch>
        <PrivateRoute path="/home" component={Home} />
        <PrivateRoute path="/admin" component={Admin} />
        <Route path="/applicationform" component={ApplicationForm} />
        {isAuthenticated ? (
          <Redirect to="/members" />
        ) : (
          <Route path="/login" component={LoginForm} />
        )}
        <Route path="/not-found" component={NotFound}></Route>
        <PrivateRoute path="/" exact component={Home} />
        <Redirect to="not-found" />
      </Switch>
    </main>
  </AuthContext.Provider>
```

After logging in, I'm suppose to redirect to the 'home' page and I also have an path set up as "/" which should re-direct me to home but only if logged in successfully.

Can you spot anything defined incorrectly in the above?

Comment: What routing/navigation library are you using? Please update your question to include a [Minimal, Complete, and Reproducible](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) code example of all relevant component code (components & routing code).

Comment: @DrewReese I've updated my question as requested. Hope that's enough. If not, let me know. Thanks

Comment: Hi, can you also include the component(s) code that is rendering the snippet where you are trying to do some navigation?

Comment: @DrewReese I've updated my answer but not with what you asked as I spotted something by accident which clearly showed me that redirecting/pushing is working but there is a problem with my routes. I'm still learning React and decided to skip some part of my course to try out the login part so I think it's best for me to continue with my course until I hit the logging in part. I'm sure it will be implemented differently from how it is implemented in the article I followed. I don't want to take any more of your time until I've checked this first. Appreciate you trying to help.